# What's meant by "regularization" of ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, regularization

What's meant by "regularization" of ODEs?

Such as, "in order to be solved by conventional ODE solvers such as ode45"?

The context where I encountered this was related to discontinuities of ODEs. And there it seemed that by adding some term or function, one may fix the discontinuous behavior.

Comment: Please give more context, making something more regular can happen in several ways for different reasons.

Answer (score 2):

To encourage simple solutions and avoid overly complicated solutions.

To make the problem more well posed and robust to noise in the data or instabilities caused by properties in the numerical solver.

You can read more here [Regularization (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics))

Comment: I know how regularization works in optimization, but how do you regularize an ODE? Add an additional term to the ODE? What kind of term would it be? If the ODE is $y'(t) = f(t, y(t))$, I'd guess we might add a term $-\gamma y(t)$ to resist the growth of $y$..

Comment: Solving an ODE can often be done as an optimization problem. Sometimes optimization problems are underdetermined.

Comment: The optimization approach often tries to rewrite the ODE as some norm minimization. For example $\min \int |y'(t) - f(t,y(t))|dt$ Then the regularization comes outside of this on it's own terms.